# evaluateJavaScript() in WKWebView works only the first time

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

```
var webView: WKWebView!
var oneWeek : String = "n/a"
var oneMonth : String = "n/a"
var sixMonths : String = "n/a"
var oneYear : String = "n/a"

func loadHtml() {
        let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "subscriptionTerms", ofType: "html")
        let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cssFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "popup", ofType: "css")
        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: cssFile!)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: url)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("var oneWeek = \"\(oneWeek)\"; var oneMonth = \"\(oneMonth)\"; var sixMonths = \"\(sixMonths)\"; var oneYear = \"\(oneYear)\";") { (result, error) in
        }   
    }
```

I have a button to click, which hides the terms by shrinking the view's constraints to 0, once clicked again it expands it to original size. At the same time, the loadHTML() function is called when this button is pressed.

However The very first time when the button is pressed, I can see the prices shown, correctly.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Premium Subscription Terms</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Length of subscriptions: One week (<span class="oneWeek"></span>)
...
    <script type="text/javascript">document.querySelector('.oneWeek').innerHTML = oneWeek;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The same button clicked a second time and the variables are nil.

I have set a breakpoint right before `webView.evaluateJavaScript()` to ensure that the global variables are not somehow reset.  The values are definitely set. But why is `evaluateJavaScript()` not injecting the variables in the HTML the second time?

Do I have to empty / clear the `WKWebView` beforehand?

Comment: The script is executed only once in your html. You should move the code into a function and call that function explicitly from `evaluateJavaScript`. Ideally, pass the variables to it as parameters instead of updating just `var` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the value of `var` in javascript is rather dangerous in my opinion. The script could have been already executed at the time, not even mentioning other Javascript quirks with `var`. Ideally, you should pass the values using a javascript function that would take the new values as parameters, for example:

```
function update(oneWeek, oneMonth) { // add other parameters
   document.querySelector('.oneWeek').innerHTML = oneWeek;
}
```

and then:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("update(\"\(oneWeek)\", \"\(oneMonth)\");") { (result, error) in
```

Another part of the problem is the fact that `loadHTMLString` starts the loading but we don't know whether the content has already been loaded or not when calling `evaluateJavaScript`. Ideally, you should call the update in one of the `WKNavigationDelegate` methods.

As an alternative approach, if you have the HTML, you could directly replace the values there before loading, e.g. putting some replacement templates there (e.g. `$ONE_WEEK`). That would be probably much easier to handle.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good to point out that VC needs to implement `WKNavigationDelegate` and also `webView.navigationDelegate = self`. Otherwise `webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) ` is never raised.

Comment: @Houman I am assuming the knowledge how to work with delegates :)

Comment: Sorry, I suggested this for creating the perfect answer ins terms of stackoverflow. No worries.